# insert query mysql throws PDO::exec() expects exactly 1 parameter, 2 given

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, sql-insert

I've pieced together some code I've gleaned from the internet: I'm trying to scan a directory to insert file names and index into MariaDB table.  My last hurdle it seems is this PDO error: PDO::exec() expects exactly 1 parameter, 2 given on line 55.  I've tagged line(55) with '//error thrown here'.
My novice guess is it doesn't like the parameters escaped in []??

As noted above novice here...
Any insight/help is greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

```
<?php

    $host = 'localhost';
    $dbname = 'dirdb';
    $username = 'root';
    $password = '';

    // Create connection
try {
  $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
  // set the PDO error mode to exception
  $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
  echo "Connected successfully";
} catch(PDOException $e) {
  echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
}   

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$dir = './recipes';

$GLOBALS['I'] = 0; // root folder given index 0

function dirToArray( $dir , $parent) {
    $result = array();
    $cdir = scandir($dir);
    foreach ($cdir as $key => $value) {
        if (!in_array($value, array(".", "..")))  {
            if (is_dir($dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $value)){

                $result[$value] = [++$GLOBALS['I']]; // add folder index
                $result[$value][] = $parent; // add parent folder index

                $result[$value][] = dirToArray($dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $value, $GLOBALS['I']);
            } else {
                $result[] = $value;
            }
        }
    }
    return $result;
}

$res = dirToArray($dir, $GLOBALS['I']);


function dirToDb($res, $parentId = 0)
{global $conn;
    foreach ($res as $key => $value) {
        if (is_array($value))  {
            $conn->exec ("insert into sp_files (path, parentId) VALUES (?, ?)", [$key, $parentId]);  //error thrown here
            dirToDb($value, $conn->fetch("SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()"));
        } else {
            $conn->exec ("insert into sp_files (path, parentId) VALUES (?, ?)", [$value, $parentId]);
        }
    }
}

//$res = dirToArray($dir);

dirToDb($res);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use `$conn->exec()` to execute a query with parameters. You have to use `prepare()` to create a statement, then execute the prepared statement.

There's also no `$conn->fetch()` method. `fetch()` is a method of the `PDOStatement` class, you can use it either with a prepared statement or the result of a query. But you don't need to perform a query to get `LAST_INSERT_ID()`, PDO has an `insertId()` method for this.

```
function dirToDb($res, $parentId = 0) {
    global $conn;
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("insert into sp_files (path, parentId) VALUES (?, ?)");
    foreach ($res as $key => $value) {
        $stmt->execute([$key, $parentId]); 
        if (is_array($value))  {
            dirToDb($value, $stmt->insertId);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for pointing me in the right direction, the foreach statement (you fixed) branched into an if statement... I'll try rework the if statement with how you structured the first half.